# ENOENT: no such file or directory Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to import images I have stored in a folder called resources located under the server section.

When I place the images in the app folder on my local drive, it works fine, but since this has to be deployed to our live server, it makes things hard to have to copy files back and forth.

The error I get:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../../resources/cp_pdf_logo.png'
> at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
> at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:453:35)
> at RouteEmails.orderAuth (C:\Development\kaizen\server\routes\emails\file:\C:\Development\kaizen\server\routes\emails\func.js:187:43)
> at RouteEmails.sendMail (C:\Development\kaizen\server\routes\emails\file:\C:\Development\kaizen\server\routes\emails\func.js:430:17)
> at RouteOrders.orderAuthorizedMail (C:\Development\kaizen\server\routes\orders\file:\C:\Development\kaizen\server\routes\orders\func.js:840:24)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at RequestRouter._routeRequest (C:\Development\kaizen\server\socketController\file:\C:\Development\kaizen\server\socketController\requestRouter.ts:64:34)
> at RequestRouter.processMessage (C:\Development\kaizen\server\socketController\file:\C:\Development\kaizen\server\socketController\requestRouter.ts:43:9)
> at Socket. (C:\Development\kaizen\server\socketController\file:\C:\Development\kaizen\server\socketController\socketClient.ts:62:7) {
> errno: -4058,
> syscall: 'open',
> code: 'ENOENT',
> path: '../../resources/cp_pdf_logo.png'
> }

Here is an example of my code:

```
let ordercplogo = this.base64_encode("../../resources/cp_pdf_logo.png")
    let orderthankyoulogo = this.base64_encode("../../resources/thankyou_logo.png")
    // let ordercplogo = this.base64_encode("/app/resources/cp_pdf_logo.png");
    // let orderthankyoulogo = this.base64_encode("/app/resources/thankyou_logo.png");
```

The commented-out section is what works, but from the image below you can see that I have these files stored inside the app.

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

PS. I have also tried to import the images above with

```
const logo1 = require("../../resources/image.png")
```

but also doesn't work and throws another error.

Comment: print the current working directory, more than likely your app isn't running where you think it is and you are a directory level off in your code. `console.log(process.cwd())`

Answer (score 1):

Your function probably tries to find the image relative to the working directory. It makes a difference if you were to do `cd /; node /app/index.js` or `cd /app; node index.js`. The working directory may be different in your live environment than locally.

There are a number of functions to help you find the path to a file in the built-in `path` module.

Let's assume you're in a file called `routes/companies/a.js`:

```
const { resolve } = require('path');

this.base64_encode(resolve(__dirname, "../../resources/cp_pdf_logo.png"));
// Will find the absolute path to the file.
```

( [`path.relative`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/path.html#pathresolvepaths) documentation page )

In CommonJS files (files that use `require()`) the value `__filename` always refers to *the file it's in, rather than the main script file* (so `/app/routes/companies.a.js` in this example) and `__dirname` is the directory it's in. That's the same value, without the `a.js` part.

Comment: You could also solve this by putting the file path resolution in the `base64_encode` function. It takes multiple paths so you could do `resolve(__dirname, '../../', file_requested_by_user)`.